# Can derived class have two sets of virtual functions?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, virtual-functions

Is it possible to have a derived class to have two sets of the same virtual functions as the base class?  I'm looking to do something like the following.  The idea being able to choose between two sets of function pointers.

```
class Base
{
    virtual void func1;
    virtual void func2;
};

class Derived: Base
{
    float somemember;

    void somefunction()
    {
        Base* func = this->derived_functions1;
    }
    class derived_functions1
    {
        virtual void func1()
        {
           return somemember*100;
        }
        virtual void func2;
    };
    class derived_functions2
    {
        virtual void func1;
        virtual void func2;
    };
};
```

Comment: I believe you're just creating two derivations, which are supposed to be separate classes. And maybe you need additional class to aggregate them and to pick the proper one. Can't tell much based on your reasoning.

Answer (score 3):

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void func1();

    virtual ~Base(){}
};

struct Impl1 : Base
{
    void func1() override {}
};

struct Impl2 : Base
{
    void func1() override {}
};

struct Derived :  Base
{
    Derived(std::unique_ptr<Base> implementation) :
        impl(std::move(implementation))
    {}

    void func1() override { impl->func1(); }

    void changeImpl(std::unique_ptr<Base> implementation)
    {
        impl = std::move(implementation);
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<Base> impl;
};
```

Comment: Base must also have a virtual destructor, or `unique_ptr<Base>` cannot delete the ImplX properly.

Comment: Well, .... in fact it CAN delete them properly because unique_ptr sets a inner "deleter" templetised to the type of the receiving objet. But having a virtual dtor can make unique_ptr implementation to be chosen from a simpler and more "space saving" one. It mostly depend on how smart is the unique_ptr implementation. Anyway, better not to risk

Comment: Yes, a base class with virtual functions should always have a virtual dtor.

Comment: Thank you all for your help!  Will these functors be able to access members of the derived class? I edited func1 in the derived class to reflect what I'm looking for.

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia aren't you confusing the "inner deleter" with `shared_ptr`? In `unique_ptr` the deleter is not "inner" in the sense of type-erasure, it's a second template argument, defaulted to `std::default_delete<Base>`, wich simply calls `delete` on the owned `Base` pointer. So you *do* need the virtual dtor.

Comment: @hansmaad as *almost* any general statement, that is not correct. Virtual dtors are only needed if objects of derived classes shall be delete polymorphically. There are cases where that is not the case, but where the class still has virtual functions. In those cases, the destructor of the base class should be protected and nonvirtual.

Comment: @riotburn No, you have to pass all needed information to the Impl instances, by passing a reference to `Derived` or just a part of the data.

Comment: @riotburn you can make the `Impl*` classes inner classes of `Derived`. They will have access to `Derived`'s private members but will need a pointer/reference to the `Derived` they belong to. For the record: the `Impl*` classes need not be derivates of `Base`, you could make your own `Impl` class hierarchy, e.g. if `Base` has member variables that are not needed for the `Impl` classes. For further reading: this is called Strategy Pattern.

Comment: I ended up making two structs (function pointers) outside of the base class, and then assigning my base class pointer by base* func = new outside_struct1(mem1, mem2...).  This worked with the original design of my code.

Answer (score 1):

Not the way you did. But you can make both the inner `class derived_functionsX` to be themseves `public: Base`, than have your main `Derived` to contain a `std::unique_ptr<Base> ptr`you can set to `new derived_functions1` or `new derived_functions2`
and implement in `Derived` `func1` and `func2` to call `ptr->func1()` and `ptr->func2()`.

For all that to work properly, `Base` must also have a `virtual ~Base() {}` otherwise no proper deletion can be done.

Answer (score 0):

In this example, it won't compile, since `derived_function1` and `derived_functions2` aren't inheriting from `Base`.

But you could have something like this:

```
class Base
{
    virtual void func1();
    virtual void func2();
};

class Wrapper    {
  public:
    Wrapper(int arg)
    {
        switch(arg)
        {
        case 1:
            b = new derived_functions1;
            break;
        case 2: 
            b = new derived_functions2;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "bad value of arg" << arg << endl;
            exit(1);
        }
    }
 ~Wrapper()
 {
    delete b;
 }
 Base* GetClass()
 {
    return b;
 }
 private:
    Base *b;

    class derived_functions1: public Base
    {
        virtual void func1();
        virtual void func2();
    };
    class derived_functions2: public Base
    {
        virtual void func1();
        virtual void func2();
    };
};
```

Comment: I've edited the code to make it more leak-safe (and hopefully compile). My point was more to show the concept in a simple way.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: **No.** A class can override inherited virtual functions only once.

However, there is a design pattern that exchanges function's behavior on the fly, called **Strategy Pattern**. In short: the class that has exchangeable behavior has a pointer to a Strategy base class that defines the interface for that behavior. It is populated with concrete Strategy classes. The function that has different behavior just delegates its calls to the Strategy pointer. Here's an example, tailored to your question:

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual void func1() = 0;
    virtual void func2() = 0;

    virtual ~Base(){}
};

#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Derived : public Base
{
  struct F1Strategy { 
    virtual void f1Impl() = 0; 
    virtual ~F1Strategy() {}
  };

  struct Impl1 : F1Strategy {
    void f1Impl() override { std::cout << "one!\n"; }
  };

  struct Impl2 : F1Strategy {
    void f1Impl() override { std::cout << "two?\n"; }
  };    

  std::unique_ptr<F1Strategy> f1Strategy;
public:
  Derived() 
    : f1Strategy(new Impl1())
  {}

  void func1() override { f1Strategy->f1Impl(); }

  void func2() override { 
    static std::unique_ptr<F1Strategy> otherStrategy(new Impl2());
    f1Strategy.swap(otherStrategy);
  }
};

int main() {
  std::unique_ptr<Base> pb(new Derived());
  pb->func1();  //  ==> one!
  pb->func2();  //swap
  pb->func1();  //  ==> two?
  pb->func1();  //  ==> two?
  pb->func2();  //swap
  pb->func1();  //  ==> one!
}
```

See it in action: http://ideone.com/zk3UTI